# Mplayer subtitle change color in config file

Tags: configuration, fonts, colors, mplayer, subtitle

How change ***mplayer*** subtitle from **white** to **yellow**? Also how change subtitle font to Ubuntu-font-family ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

Edit your mplayer config file **(/home/user/.mplayer/config)** and add these lines:

```
font = "Ubuntu"
ass-font-color = "ffff0000"
ass-font-scale = "2"
```

Let's say you have a video named **video.avi** and the subtitles in the same folder eg:*(home/user/Videos)* named **subtitle.srt**.

Then to open a video with mplayer in full screen from the command line type:

```
cd /home/user/Videos
mplayer video.avi -sub subtitle.srt -fs -ass
```

*(You can change the value of "ass-font-scale" acoording to your needs.)*

If you are using mplayer-gui to open the video, make sure you have SSA/ASS enable,right-click in mplayer-gui and go to **Preferences**.

In the tab **"Subtitles & OSD"** click in **"SSA/ASS subtitle rendering"**

[image]

If you want to change another option like font scaling just go to  the "Font" tab.

[image]

*(Maybe after changing some options you have to restart the mplayer-gui.)*

Hope this will be helpful!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

edit  ~/.mplayer/config

```
#put the path to the desired font
font=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/impact.ttf

ffactor="10" #black outline
sub-bg-alpha="0" #background color ala closed captions
sub-bg-color="0" #black to white
subfont-text-scale="3.7"    #truetype font scaling
subfont-blur="1" #Slight blur
```

not sure about color codes, but you can play 0-255

Comment: not work [shot0001.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3117811/shot0001.png)